# Combine two dataframes on one level of multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Consider two dataframes `df_a` and `df_b`. `df_a` has a multiindex. `df_b` has a regular index. The first level of the multiindex of `df_a` matches the index of `df_b`. I want to divide (or add, subtract or multiply) dataframe `df_a` with `df_b` matching the first level of the index of `df_a` with the index of `df_b`.

```
import pandas
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,8,4],
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2]]))
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data=[2, 4], index=['A', 'B'])
```

The operation `df_a / df_b` (after whatever coding is necessary) should give something like this

```
A 1  .5  
  2  1
B 1  2
  2  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `div` with `level`

```
df_a.div(df_b,axis=0,level=0)
Out[30]: 
       0
A 1  0.5
  2  1.0
B 1  2.0
  2  1.0
```

Comment: Wow! It doesn't get much nicer than that. Thanks.